# ContentEditable label with checkbox inside loses focus

Tags: javascript, html

On Chrome (and possibly other WebKit based browsers too), I have an issue where if a checkbox is wrapped inside a label and the label has the attribute contenteditable=true, Chrome fails to focus properly on the label.

```html
<label contenteditable="true">hello <input type="checkbox" /></label>
```

Clicking on the text fails to focus and instead checks the checkbox.

To focus on the text, it is necessary to select some text and then click on the selection to see the cursor blinking.

To see the wanted behaviour, check on Internet Explorer 11. Clicking on the text itself selects the text, and clicking on the checkbox selects the checkbox.

Is there any fix to this (other than changing the HTML)?

Comment: Actually that is what a label is supposed to do: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Comment: Indeed, a label is supposed to click the input inside of it. However, when the label is contenteditable, shouldn't clicking on the text node inside the label place the cursor instead of clicking the input beside it?

Comment: Depends on your point of view.. but why not just use a span and let html elements do what they are supposed to do?

Comment: @BinarMorker No. Why should the `contenteditible` alter the native behavior?

Comment: This content is user-generated in an editor. I cannot go back and change everything to a span. I agree that changing it to a span would work, but this solution seems unfeasible to me.

Comment: I guess you have to try a preventDefault on the labels click event in that case.

Comment: I agree with you @Scott Marcus. The label actually behaves as expected, but it seems so counterintuitive and makes it hard for users inside my editor to edit text inside their labels.

Comment: <label contenteditable="true" onclick="event.preventDefault()">hello <input type="checkbox" onclick="event.stopPropagation();" /></label>

Comment: @Lain Putting on preventDefault works, but I will have to try it in my editor to see if it cancels other events properly. I think you should post it as an answer.

Comment: But if you cancel the event, then the label won't work at all and what you've got left is effectively a `span` at that point, so a `span` should be used. Remember the `label` is an element that assists in form navigation. If you are going to break that functionality, don't use it.

Comment: This is not an issue here. The javascript I will try on the editor will not be on the final site where the content appears. The event will only be canceled inside the editor, not once its content is saved.

Comment: I figured I would offer some kind of closure. I was able to prevent the default event onclick, but it was really too complicated to make it work with all the other events that had to happen too. We decided to go with dynamically replacing with a span element instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what a label is supposed to do. They make interacting with form field easier (especially on small devices). It is for better UI accessibility.

> To see the wanted behaviour, check on Internet Explorer 11. Clicking
>   on the text itself selects the text, and clicking on the checkbox
>   selects the checkbox.

You'll need to just use a `<span>` instead:

```html
<span contenteditable="true">hello <input type="checkbox" /></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Actually that is what a label is supposed to do](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)

If you insist on doing it as a label you have to prevent the default behaviour of it and cancel the propagation on the checkbox itself:

```
<!-- Dirty example -->
<label contenteditable="true" onclick="event.preventDefault()">hello <input type="checkbox" onclick="event.stopPropagation();" /></label>
```

Like I commented before, I would not recommend this. Let the labels do what they are supposed to do and use a span instead.

Comment: Considering that `label` is the given element, this is the correct answer. I had the same case where the user can edit an existing form "in place", so labels cannot be replaced with spans.